wxWidgets application crashes on arch linux, but not on windows
I've been trying to create a wxWidgets C++ application under my EndeavourOS (should be arch linux at it's core).
My Desktop Environment is KDE Plasma (Wayland). But I the same problems occur on GNOME, and XFCE also.
I was already successful compiling a wxWidgets C++ application under Windows.
But on Linux, my compiled simple Program:
// g++ main.cpp -o prog `wx-config --cppflags --libs`
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyFrame: public wxFrame{
    public:
    MyFrame() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "WxWidgets Linux Program") {
        wxPanel* mainPanel = new wxPanel(this);
        wxButton* cancel = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Cancel");
        SetClientSize(500, 50); // it seems that this makes the program crash
        Center(); // and this also
    }
};

class App : public wxApp {
public:
    bool OnInit() {
        MyFrame* w = new MyFrame();
        w->Show();

        return true;
    }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(App);

...crashes:
./prog: /usr/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0: no version information available (required by ./prog)
./prog: /usr/lib/libwx_baseu-3.2.so.0: no version information available (required by ./prog)
./prog: Symbol `_ZTV8wxButton' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
./prog: Symbol `_ZTV9wxControl' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
./prog: Symbol `_ZTV12wxButtonBase' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
./prog: Symbol `_ZTV11wxAnyButton' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
./prog: Symbol `_ZTV11wxPanelBase' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
./prog: Symbol `_ZTV7wxPanel' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
./prog: Symbol `_ZTV17wxMDIClientWindow' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
./prog: Symbol `_ZTV7wxFrame' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
// english translation: Memory access error (memory dump written)

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

This is the stacktrace I get with gdb:
User
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00006e6f74747562 in ??? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7950f43 in wxWindow::PreCreation (this=this@entry=0x55555566ef80, parent=parent@entry=0x555555724500, pos=..., size=...) at /usr/src/debug/wxwidgets/wxWidgets-3.2.4/src/gtk/window.cpp:2953
#2  0x00007ffff79533f3 in wxWindow::Create (this=0x55555566ef80, parent=0x555555724500, id=-1, pos=..., size=..., style=2621440, name=...) at /usr/src/debug/wxwidgets/wxWidgets-3.2.4/src/gtk/window.cpp:2841
#3  0x00007ffff77abf16 in wxPanelBase::Create (this=0x55555566ef80, parent=<optimized out>, id=<optimized out>, pos=<optimized out>, size=<optimized out>, style=<optimized out>, name=...) at /usr/src/debug/wxwidgets/wxWidgets-3.2.4/src/common/panelcmn.cpp:98
#4  0x0000555555564da0 in wxPanel::wxPanel(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) ()
#5  0x0000555555565b84 in MyFrame::MyFrame() ()
#6  0x0000555555565da0 in App::OnInit() ()
#7  0x0000555555563e79 in wxAppConsoleBase::CallOnInit() ()
#8  0x00007ffff70f1452 in wxEntry (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/wxwidgets/wxWidgets-3.2.4/src/common/init.cpp:481
#9  0x000055555556354b in main ()

The strange thing is: the following code runs just fine (except that scaling the window sometimes hangs the program)
#include <wx/wx.h>

class App : public wxApp {
public:
    bool OnInit() {
        
        wxFrame* window = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "GUI Test", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(600, 400));
        wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
        wxStaticText* text = new wxStaticText(window, wxID_ANY, "Well Done!\nEverything seems to be working",
            wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL);
        text->SetFont(wxFont(20, wxFONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_NORMAL));
        sizer->Add(text);
        window->SetClientSize(300, 300);
        window->SetSizer(sizer);
        window->Show();
        return true;
    }
};


what is your wx version? Do you have the same version in Windows? Did you build the library yourself or install it from the repo? Can you successfully build and run the minimal sample provided to you by the library?

My first suspicion would be that you're combining different headers and libraries (i.e. they might not match).

@Igor Version 3.2.4.0 is the one I use (according to wx-config --version-full). FOr the library - I installed wxwidgets via the console, but that resulted in the errors I posted above. Then I built the library myself (downloaded the most current version from the official wxWidgets website) - resulting in the same problems.
I have the same wxwidgets version on windows, but this should not matter as the code I provided was run isolated, in a new directory under Linux.
Unfortunately, I dont really understand how to build the minimal sample -At least I found it myself (beginner here)

@ChristianStieber judging by the other comments below, I believe that myself now. But how can I check where I link against the wrong libs? I am really confused why every yt tutorial that shows how to compile a simple wxwidgets program fails only on my machine.

@tbone, use what repo manager you distro uses to uninstall the library you installed. Get rid of it completely. (More than likely it is inside the /usr/lib{64}/wx. If you did run make install run make distclean from the build directory. Or if you prefer - re-install the OS. Download the sources and build it manually. Don't run make install. Now do - "g++ *.cpp -o test ``/full/path/to/wx-config --cxxflags --libs`"

@tbone, the idea is to have only one wxWidgets copy on the machine. I will try to give you step by step instructions in the answer on how to build the library and the sample.

To build the library and the minimal sample:
cd wxWidgets 
mkdir buildGTK
cd buildGTK
../configure --enable-debug --with-gtk && make -j4
cd samples/minimal
make
./minimal

That should build the library and minimal sample.
Let us know if you get any errors during this process.
Remember - this has to be done on the "clean emvironment" - no installed version of wxWidgets.
Then after everything is complete and you have the minimal sample running do:
g++ *.cpp -o test `/full/path/to/wx-config --cxxflags --libs`


Incredible - that one worked!
What I have done yet is uninstalling the remains of other wx installations - but I just used the path to the buildGTK folder when it came to the wx-config part and - boom!
However, building the minimal sample with your last g++ command failed - but nonetheless that made my sample code work!
I still don't get what I could have done wrong by installing wxwidgets like all the videos on youtube stated.
Well, I guess now I have to uninstall all previous wxwidgets and try to install the buildGTK wxWidgets somewhere on my drive :)

@tbone, please understand - I didn't suggest to build the minimal sampler with g++. All I did is to tell you to go to the directory of buildGTK/samples/minimal and issue make command. The g++ command you references is for you own code. But you don't need to build the sample anymore. Just keep the library that you build and everything will be fine.

@tbone, also keep in mind that building the samples is always a good idea - it will show you what the current release is capable of and it will help you verify the functionality if you will need a reproducer for something that fails.

Ah, now I also see that I misunderstood the last part, where I though I needed / could do g++ to build the minimal sample again.
But I know - I don't need the minimal example for my projects. Yesterday I took your g++ Command and placed it into my project and voilà, it worked :D
Now I also understood the Importance of those examples.
Thank you very much :)

@tbone, yes, this is it. The only reason I mention building minimal instruction is because people get confused with Makwdile in the sample directory and build directory on nox. But you dont need it since everything works.

I agree with the analysis that there is likely an ODR violation. This is most likely (with this reproducer) caused by conflicting versions of libraries at build vs. runtime.
On my NixOs box I've built with a simple nix-shell:

Now, NixOs is great at separating dependencies, but on a regular Linux the paths won't be unique and instead you may see something like /usr/lib/x86_64/libwx_gtk...-.so symlinked to a specific version. If that's not the version you're building against then you will risk UB due to the ODR violation.
Note that it doesn't have to be about Wx/GTK versions. It might be any runtime linker dependency.
Note:

interactive Gnome3/Wayland demo


interactive KDE Plasma5/Wayland demo




PS. I'm running Hyprland/Wayland. Will also test under Gnome/Wayland just in case some weird Wx bug interferes.

No problem on Gnome/Wayland https://imgur.com/a/D7mybFT

Also no problem on Plasma5/Wayland https://imgur.com/a/D7mybFT . I do note that the hardcoded size (500, 50) seems to be smaller than the minimum height according to Plasma5's interactive resizing (see for yourself in the vid).  This might well have something to do with it. My Plasma shell is v5.27.11. Perhaps a GTK or window-manager bug was already fixed in this area?

Why do you ignore the warnings about ABI incompatibility that you get and that clearly indicate the problem?
You're not saying anything about how you build your application but these messages unambiguously show that it is using libraries not matching the headers it was compiled with. You need to fix this by ensuring that you link with the correct libraries and that the same libraries (and not some different variant) are found during run-time.

Dear VZ.,
Hm, it seems that the sidenote on my questions "I am a bloody beginner in all of this" got removed.
I did not ignore the warnings. I just do not understand those. Why being so toxic?
How can I ensure the correct linking - how do I even know which lib file is causing the problem?

@tbone VZ is not being toxic. He’s stating unambiguously what the problem is. Rather than being offended, accept that he has directly answered your asked question. If you need help understanding the answer, then simply ask for it.
